# Babel cache configs: Difference between cache.using and cache.invalidate methods?

Tags: javascript, caching, babeljs, console.log

I'm trying to understand which caching method is more suitable for my needs, as I'm needing to apply `transform-remove-console` plugin when building in `production` environment.

[Babel > Config Files documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files) is vague about the differences between `using` and `invalidate` methods?

> api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV) - Cache based on the value
>   of NODE_ENV. Any time the using callback returns a value other than
>   the one that was expected, the overall config function will be called
>   again **and a new entry will be added to the cache**.
>
> api.cache.invalidate(() => process.env.NODE_ENV) - Cache based on the
>   value of NODE_ENV. Any time the using callback returns a value other
>   than the one that was expected, the overall config function will be
>   called again **and all entries in the cache will be replaced with the
>   result**.

Here is my config:

```js
module.exports = (api) => {
  // Is this better?
  var isProd = api.cache.invalidate(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
  // Or this one perhaps?
  // var isProd = api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
  var plugins = [];
  if (isProd) {
    plugins.push(['transform-remove-console', { exclude: ['error', 'warn', 'info'] }]);
  }
  return {
    presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'],
    plugins,
  };
};
```